# Graduate or Undergraduate?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, undergraduate

Is someone who is currently pursuing his Integrated Master's course/ Dual Degree course (or any other 5-year degree course) considered to be a graduate student or an undergraduate student?

Comment: That depends on the institution if you are in the US. Elsewhere it may depend on law or custom.

Comment: Considered by whom, and for what purpose?

Comment: The ones that I have knowledge of award the Bachelor's degree after the fourth year. Until that point the student is an undergraduate, after a grad student. Context: hiring summer students and trying to figure out which position(s) they are eligible for. No bachelor degree awarded, not a grad student.

Comment: Graduate students already have an undergraduate degree.

Comment: Coterm: usually undergrad, 5th year masters: grad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the literal meaning of the word, you're an undergraduate until you graduate. Then you are called a post-graduate student (British English) or graduate student (American English) if you continue studying for a higher degree, or simply a graduate if you are no longer a student.

However, your university may use these words differently or use different words altogether, and their meaning and usage also varies across countries and cultures.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on institution. For example two places I know which offered Honours degree (3-year Bachelor's, +1 year with research project for so-called Honours), one of them considered Honours students undergraduates, while the other considered them postgraduates. Similarly there are undergraduates who take graduate courses, and graduates who take undergraduate courses.

I imagine however if a student is enrolled in a program that results in a Masters degree, he or she would be a graduate student, no questions asked.